# Google Shopping API: Price comparison

Tags: web-services, google-shopping

Is there any way to develop a price comparison app using this API? We have a wholesale client who wants to check its retailers' prices. The app should call the api and get all product prices from different vendors using a Keyword (e.g "Nikon camera").

I have made a quick research and apparently, that option is no longer available.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Correct - this option is now gone and you're unable to query this data from Google. M.

Comment: It actually is possible, but it requires scraping the data. It can be done but you need a nice amount of proxies.